# Swift 2 Is it possible to add a web link to an annotation callout?

Tags: swift2, mkmapview, xcode7, mkannotation

I'm able to create pin's with their popup's as well as the info-light button to the right.  And when tapped, the info button pops up an alert with some text and an "ok" button at the bottom.  Is it now possible to add a link at the bottom of the text that will direct the user to a URL, saw wikkipedia for example  in safari?

I've used the following called function to succesfully do so with a regular button in the mapview, but I can't figure out how to implement it the way I've stated above

```
@IBAction func webLink(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.wikipedia.com") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```